# Find value of $p$ such that $\sum |b_n|^p $ converges

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X , \|\cdot \|)=(\ell^2, \|\cdot \|_2)$. Let $e_n \in \ell^2$. Fora bounded linear functional $\phi$ on $X$, let $b_n=\phi (e_n)$ for each $n \geq 1$. Find the value of $p \geq 1$ such that the series such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n|^p$ necessarily converges.

---

With this sum, wouldnt it only have one term because of the $e_n$? I know that $e_n$ gets mapped by the linear functional but since all terms besudes the nth term is zero, it would remain zero once it is mapped wont it? If it has one term, then obviously it converges.